# How to take out int value from JSON object?

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5

I'm working with Laravel 5 right now and I have the following problem. I've got response from DB query:

> `[{"id":1}]`

and I want to take out 1 as int or string. Any ideas?

I've tried to solve this like follows:

```
$json = (DB query);       
$data = json_decode($json);     
$final = $data[0]->id;
```

and response is :

> json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: have you tried to decode it using `json_decode` ?

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? (Google search for example xD)

Comment: yeah, I've googled a little but I don't understand any of examples, that's why I ask Here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I extract data from JSON with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php)

Comment: `json_decode('[{"id": 1}]', true)[0]['id']`

Comment: @AlexAndrei now i've got an array in response, my code looks like:                   $variable = json_decode(DB query);

Answer (score 2):

This is all you need.

```
$response = json_decode($response); // Decode the JSON
$string = $response[0]->id;         // Save the value of id var
```

Comment: Outer array was missed

Comment: Oops, thats why we don't `json_decode` in our heads, edited.

Answer (score 1):

As you say, the string you have is in JSON format, so you need to use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to access it in PHP.

The square brackets refer to an array, and the braces refer to an object within that array, so what you're looking for is the `id` value of the first element (i.e. element `0`) in the array.

```
<?php
$json = '[{"id":1}]';
$data = json_decode($json);

echo $data[0]->id;
// 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$json_array = '[{"id":1}]';
$data = json_decode($json_array);
print_r($data); // To display the result array
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to decode it, if I'm not misunderstanding your questions.

```
$json = '[{"id":1}]';
$decodedObject = json_decode($json);
```

Then you can loop through the aray and do something with your data:

```
foreach($decodedObject as $key => $value) {
    $id = $value->id;
}
```

If you're using Laravel, though, why not use Eloquent models?

Comment: i'm fresh with laravel, can you tell me how to use Eloquent model to do this?

Comment: I was hoping you'd ask! What's your query? Show me your query, and I'll show you how to do it with an Eloquent model.